# How to transform selected rows into a single column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a data frame which I need to transform. I need to change the unique rows into single columns based on the value of a column.

My data below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b","b"), 
                  V2 = c("product1", "transport", "product1", "product2","transport"),
                  V3 = c("100", "10", "100", "100","10"))

> df1
  V1        V2  V3
1  a  product1 100
2  a transport  10
3  b  product1 100
4  b  product2 100
5  b transport  10
```

I need the following transformation and the division of the value of V3 into the number of products included in V1.

```
> df2
  V1       V2 transport  V3
1  a product1        10 100
2  b product1         5 100
3  b product2         5 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method with `data.table` - convert to `data.table` (`setDT`), make sure that the 'V3' is `numeric` (for division - it was created as character), grouped by 'V1', create the 'transport' by extracting the 'V3' value where 'V2' is 'transport' and divide by the number of elements in 'V2' that are not "transport", then subset the data by removing the 'transport' elements from 'V2'

```
library(data.table)
df1$V3 <- as.numeric(df1$V3)
setDT(df1)[, transport := V3[V2 == "transport"]/
       sum(V2 != "transport"), by = V1]
df1[V2 != "transport"]
       V1       V2    V3 transport
   <char>   <char> <num>     <num>
1:      a product1   100        10
2:      b product1   100         5
3:      b product2   100         5
```

---

Or another option with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(transport = case_when(V2 == 'transport' ~ V3)) %>% 
   group_by(V1) %>%
   fill(transport, .direction = "downup") %>%
   mutate(transport = transport/sum(V2 != "transport")) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   filter(V2 != "transport")
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  V1    V2          V3 transport
  <chr> <chr>    <int>     <dbl>
1 a     product1   100        10
2 b     product1   100         5
3 b     product2   100         5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tidyverse-based solution, using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

1. convert `V3` to numeric
2. pivot wider to create a separate column for `transport`, then pivot longer to collapse `"product1"` and `"product2"` back into one column
3. divide `transport` by number of cases per `V1`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(V3 = as.numeric(V3)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = V2, values_from = V3) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(product1, product2), 
    names_to = "V2", 
    values_to = "V3", 
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(transport = transport / n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   V1    transport V2          V3
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 a            10 product1   100
#> 2 b             5 product1   100
#> 3 b             5 product2   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach to get your desired output if I got your point right:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(V3 = ifelse(V2 == "transport", as.numeric(V3) / (n() - 1), as.numeric(V3))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V2, values_from = V3) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(product1, product2), names_to = "V2", values_to = "V3") %>%
  drop_na()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  V1    transport V2          V3
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 a            10 product1   100
2 b             5 product1   100
3 b             5 product2   100
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(V3 = as.numeric(V3)) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(transport = if_else(V2 == "transport", V3 / (n()-1), NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(transport, .direction = "up") %>% ungroup %>% 
  filter(V2 != "transport")

#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   V1    V2          V3 transport
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 a     product1   100        10
#> 2 b     product1   100         5
#> 3 b     product2   100         5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more with `pivoting`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = V2,
    values_from = V3
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(V1, transport),
    names_to = "V2",
    values_to = "V3"
  )%>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(transport = transport/max(row_number()))
```

```
  V1    transport V2          V3
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <int>
1 a            10 product1   100
2 b             5 product1   100
3 b             5 product2   100
```

Comment: Man so glad to see you here :)

Comment: Good to see you dear @Anoushiravan!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a data.table approach:

```
f <- function(p,v) {  
  ps=grepl("^p",p)
  list(V2 = p[ps], transport=rep(v[!ps]/sum(ps), sum(ps)), V3 = v[ps])
}
setDT(df1)[,f(V2,as.numeric(V3)), V1 ]

       V1       V2 transport    V3
   <char>   <char>     <num> <num>
1:      a product1        10   100
2:      b product1         5   100
3:      b product2         5   100
```